# Как передать не все параметры при объявлении экземпляра класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Как передать только второй параметр? Я задал значения по умолчанию, но второму экземпляру надо передать только второй.

```
class Car {
    public $brend;
    public $speed;
    public $color;

    public function __construct($brend = '*', $speed = 0, $color = '*'){
        $this->brend = $brend;
        $this->speed = $speed;
        $this->color = $color;
    }    
}

$car1 = new Car('Moskvych', 'Green', 15);
$car2 = new Car(200);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($car1);

/*Первый
Car Object
(
    [brend] => Moskvych
    [speed] => 120
    [color] => Green
)
*/

echo '<pre>';
print_r($car2);

/*Второй

Вот что получается
Car Object
(
    [brend] => 200 // скорость передалась в бренд (по умолчанию *) 
    [speed] => 0 // осталось по умолчанию
    [color] => *
)
*/
```

Comment: Так может быть:`$car2 = new Car('',200,'');`

Comment: никак. передавайте `*` в качестве значения для первого параметра. нельзя просто взять и передать только второй. А вообще рассмотрите вариант передачи одного параметра - массива конфигурации, это будет куда удобнее.

Comment: По поводу моего вопроса, такое принимают на практике? Кто то сказал что это просто костыли, и я так понял что не часто или вообще нет .

Comment: Да, это костыли, и еще костыльнее было бы использование func_get_args с переменным количеством аргументов или просто ассоциативного массива.

Comment: Использованием $car->speed = 200; и конструктор по умолчанию. Не нужно городить костыли на костылях, если можно использовать стандартные инструменты, облегчающие и вам читабельность кода, и сокращающие время выяснения что, где и как работает.

Comment: Если бы да кабы, @Эдуард ;) У вас оно же не инкапсулировано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот пример - всего лишь мой взгляд на решение задачи. Я думаю, что если нужно вызывать класс с параметрами по умолчанию, которые или редко изменяются, или изменяются частично, то можно объявить свойства со значениями по умолчанию прямо в классе *(а не перезаписывать свойства в конструкторе класса)*.

Свойства класса я бы сделал не доступными для чтения и записи вне самого класса. Для доступа к ним можно написать пару соответствующих методов. А в случае попытки записи в не существующее свойство класса бросать исключение.

Реализация с параметрами по умолчанию:

```
$car1 = new Car;

var_dump( $car1->getProperties() );
```

Передача одного параметра **двумя аргументами**, где:

```
speed - имя перезаписываемого свойства класса
200   - новое значение
```

*(остальные - по умолчанию)*:

```
$car2 = new Car;
$car2->setProperty('speed', 200);

var_dump( $car2->getProperties() );
```

Передача нескольких параметров **одним аргументом** - ассоциативным массивом, ключи которого соответствуют названиям свойств, а значения - новым значениям:

```
$car2->setProperty([
    'brend' => 'Volga', 
    'color' => 'Red'
]);

var_dump( $car2->getProperties() );
```

При попытке передачи не существующих свойств будет брошено исключение, и использованы значения свойств по умолчанию:

```
$car3 = new Car;
$car3->setProperty([
    'my_brend' => 'Kamaz', 
    'color' => 'Lime',
    'speed' => 500
]);

var_dump( $car3->getProperties() );
```

---

Код класса:

```
class Car 
{
    /**
     * Свойства класса со значениями по умолчанию
     */
    private $brend = 'Moskvych';
    private $color = 'Green';
    private $speed = 150;

    /**
     * Метод для проверки свойств и генерации исключений
     */
    private function propertyExists($property)
    {
        if (! property_exists(__CLASS__, $property)) {
            $message = "Обращение к не существующему свойству: $property !";
            throw new Exception($message);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Метод для перезаписи свойств или выброса исключений
     */
    public function setProperty($property, $value = '')
    {        
        try {
            if (is_array($property)) {
                foreach ($property as $property => $value) {
                    $this->propertyExists($property);
                    $this->$property = $value;
                }
            } else {
                $this->propertyExists($property);
                $this->$property = $value;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<b>', $e->getMessage(), '</b>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Метод для получения всех свойств класса
     */
    public function getProperties()
    {
        foreach ($this as $property => $value) {
            $data[$property] = $value;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car {

    public $brend;
    public $speed;
    public $color;

    public function __construct($brend = '*', $speed = 0, $color = '*'){
        $this->brend = $brend;
        $this->speed = $speed;
        $this->color = $color;
    }    
}

$car1 = new Car('Moskvych', 'Green', 15);
$car2 = clone $car1;
$car2->speed = '200';
```